# Getting this error... invariant.js:42 Uncaught Error: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Ok so I am making a form that allows the user to build a quiz (like a buzzfeed quiz) but I don't want to limit the user on the number of quesitons they *must* have. So i figured I could just do something where there is an "add question" button at the bottom of the questions that lets the user add a question with all the appropriate fields. Right now I am just working on the form part, I already have logic set up to make the quiz function and stuff but all the quiz details (answers, questions, etc.) are all hard coded. I also don't know a lot (at all) about how to do these kinds of things (html, js, react, etc.) so if anything else looks funky I am open to some tips. Anyways... here's my code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

var questionNum = 1;

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
          </header>
          <p className="App-intro">
            To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
        </div>
        <form>
          Give your quiz a title:<br />
          <input type="text" name="quizTitle" /><br />
          Who's the author?<br />
          <input type="text" name="author" /><br />
          Now let's add some questions...<br />
          <form className="quesitons">
            <div id={"questions" + questionNum}>
              Question {questionNum}<br />
              <input type="text" name={"question" + questionNum}/><br />
              Answers<br />
              Check the box(es) for the correct answer(s).<br />
              <input type="checkbox" name={"question" + questionNum + "Answer1Box"} />
              <label for={"question" + questionNum + "Answer1"}><input type="text" name={"question" + questionNum + "Answer1"}/></label><br />
              <input type="checkbox" name={"question" + questionNum + "Answer2Box"} />
              <label for={"question" + questionNum + "Answer2"}><input type="text" name={"question" + questionNum + "Answer2"}/></label><br />
              <input type="checkbox" name={"question" + questionNum + "Answer3Box"} />
              <label for={"question" + questionNum + "Answer3"}><input type="text" name={"question" + questionNum + "Answer3"}/></label><br />
              <input type="checkbox" name={"question" + questionNum + "Answer4Box"} />
              <label for={"question" + questionNum + "Answer4"}><input type="text" name={"question" + questionNum + "Answer4"}/></label><br />
            </div>
            <div id="container"></div>
          </form>
        </form>
        <button id="addQuestionButton" onClick='addQuestion ()'>Add Question</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function addQuestion () {
  questionNum++;
  console.log(questionNum + "that is the question number");

  var div = document.createElement('div');

    div.className = '{"questions" + questionNum}';

    div.innerHTML =
        'Question {questionNum}<br />\
        <input type="text" name={"question" + questionNum}/><br />\
        Answers<br />\
        Check the box(es) for the correct answer(s).<br />\
        <input type="checkbox" name={"question" + questionNum + "Answer1Box"} />\
        <label for={"question" + questionNum + "Answer1"}><input type="text" name={"question" + questionNum + "Answer1"}/></label><br />\
        <input type="checkbox" name={"question" + questionNum + "Answer2Box"} />\
        <label for={"question" + questionNum + "Answer2"}><input type="text" name={"question" + questionNum + "Answer2"}/></label><br />\
        <input type="checkbox" name={"question" + questionNum + "Answer3Box"} />\
        <label for={"question" + questionNum + "Answer3"}><input type="text" name={"question" + questionNum + "Answer3"}/></label><br />\
        <input type="checkbox" name={"question" + questionNum + "Answer4Box"} />\
        <label for={"question" + questionNum + "Answer4"}><input type="text" name={"question" + questionNum + "Answer4"}/></label><br />\
        ';

    document.getElementsByClassName('questions').appendChild(div);
}

export default App;
```

(I know there's like stuff from React on my page, it's not mine, but I think it's cute for now so I am going to leave it there until I get this form working) I am getting this error when I press the "addQuestion" button...

```
invariant.js:42 Uncaught Error: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type.
```

That's not the whole error (i'll put that at the end) but I am not quite sure how to fix this. I also don't quite understand what this means so if someone could explain it that would be dope.

Here's the full error (Oh, I am getting this error in Google Chrome with the dev tools but you probably already knew that)

```
Uncaught Error: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type.
    at invariant (invariant.js:42)
    at getListener (react-dom.development.js:680)
    at listenerAtPhase (react-dom.development.js:981)
    at accumulateDirectionalDispatches (react-dom.development.js:1004)
    at traverseTwoPhase (react-dom.development.js:924)
    at accumulateTwoPhaseDispatchesSingle (react-dom.development.js:1020)
    at forEachAccumulated (react-dom.development.js:562)
    at accumulateTwoPhaseDispatches (react-dom.development.js:1063)
    at Object.extractEvents (react-dom.development.js:4396)
    at extractEvents (react-dom.development.js:697)
    at runExtractedEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:731)
    at handleTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:4476)
    at batchedUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:16659)
    at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2131)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:4555)
    at interactiveUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:16714)
    at interactiveUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2150)
    at dispatchInteractiveEvent (react-dom.development.js:4532)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onClick='addQuestion ()'` should be `onClick={addQuestion}` instead

The reason for this is JSX so though it looks like HTML, it isnt actually HTML, so there are some minor differences.

Comment: You should use `onClick={addQuestion.bind(this)}` instead

Comment: @ManavM Makes sense. I tried your suggestion but when I clicked on the button i got this error ``Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).appendChild is not a function``

Comment: @JamesMoran I realise that and the performance issues it causes. But at the same time it is code that will definitely not fail, and in this scenario personally I would prefer my code to work first before refactoring it to be more efficient..but that's me

Comment: @JamesMoran I tried your suggestiong but got this error ``Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined``

Comment: @JamesMoran addQuestion() is not a class function. @dorkycam that is probably due to the typo here `<form className="quesitons">`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question properly. You don't need to use bind in this case

Comment: Yes you can simply pass a reference to the function like `onClick={addQuestion}`

Comment: @ManavM Lol, thanks. Most of my errors are due to typos XD

Comment: @ManavM I fixed my typo and changed the onClick to ``onClick={addQuestion}`` but i still seem to be getting this error ``Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).appendChild is not a function``

Comment: Ahh yes..you see `getElementsByClassName` return a list of nodes not a single node. so you'd have to use `document.getElementsByClassName('questions')[0].appendChild(div)`

Comment: @ManavM It works but my variables inside of the thing I am adding don't seem to be variables anymore. Do you might know how I would go about that? Or better yet, is it possible to just tell `div.innerHTML` to be equal to one of my div or form tags in my og HTML (the one inside of the "App" class)?

Comment: Well to be quite honest you've managed to write the most HTML-JQuery-ish code I have ever seen in a ReactJS enviroment. Go through some ReactJS tutorials, read about Component State and how it can be manipulated to dynamically add content to your Component. You really need to refactor your codevto be more "Reactive".

Comment: @ManavM Ha, ok. Thanks for the help!